# Ng-Click events not firing

Tags: angularjs

Hi I just started learning Angular today and I have some problems when trying to bind an event.Here is what I have done so far.I loaded all my scripts on my html page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

<script src="app/modules.js"></script>

<script src="app/Controllers/studentGradesController.js"></script>
```

I then create a file modules and defined my module:

```
var angularTestApp = angular.module('AngularTestApp', []);
```

I then created a controler:

```
angularTestApp.controller('StudentGradesController', function StudentGradesController($scope) {


    $scope.students = [
       {
            firstName: 'Lorem',
            lastName: 'Ipsum',
            age: 24,
            grade: 5,
            votes: 0
       },
       {
           firstName: 'Lorem',
           lastName: 'Ipsum',
           age: 250,
           grade: 21,
           votes: 0
       }


      ...
    ];

    $scope.downVote = function(student) {
        student--;
    };
    $scope.upVote = function (student) {
        alert("I work");
    };
});
```

I then binded the controller on my html:

```
   <article class="container" ng-controller="StudentGradesController">
        <section>
            <section ng-repeat="student in students" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pointer" ng-click="upVote"></i> 
                    <span ng-bind="student.votes" class="center-block"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pointer" ng-click="downVote"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="well col-md-11">
                    <div>
                        <span ng-bind="student.firstName"></span>
                        <span ng-bind="student.lastName"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </article>
```

When I try to click on the binded items nothing happens.No errors are thrown.Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a function using ng-click instead of just referencing it.  Adding the parenthesis will make it a function call:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up pointer" ng-click="upVote(student)"></i>
```

That said; the [i tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp) is just puts text in italics and you have no text specified, so there is nothing to click on.

Comment: `fa` is used by [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) to use its icons. It will be replaced with some CSS by [this icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-up/).

Comment: `<i>` is often used for icons (for some reason). It saves 6 characters (relative to `<span>`).

Comment: Yep, I assumed it was populated w/ CSS. I should have mentioned that in the answer.  I did not know the CSS was related to Font Awesome, though.

Answer (score 3):

The argument you provide in `ng-click` is not a function, it's an AngularJS expression. It's like a Javascript expression. You should use `ng-click="upVote(student)"` to call it.

Answer (score 2):

try `ng-click="downVote(student)"` and `ng-click="upVote(student)"`